# Deduplicate in PROC SQL based on certain column information

Tags: sql, sas

So I have the following data

```
ID | Status
________________
1  | In Progress
2  | In Progress
3  | Done
3  | In Progress
4  | Backlog
5  | Backlog
5  | In Progress
6  | Done
7  | Backlog
7  | In Progress
7  | Done
```

However, I would like to have only one ID when there are multiple IDs based on the information in the Status column. So corresponding to ID 3 we have the statuses `Done` and `In Progress`. Here I would like to keep `Done` and discard `In Progress`. For ID 7 I would like to keep `Done` and discard the other two statuses.

So the end result would be:

```
 ID | Status
________________
1  | In Progress
2  | In Progress
3  | Done
4  | Backlog
5  | In Progress
6  | Done
7  | Done
```

The problem is with ID 5 for example when it's not `Done` yet, but is `In Progress`.

I have tried to do it with a CASE WHEN statement, but because I give it an order of importance it also keeps the second option. So if I would say:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Status = 'Done' THEN 1
            WHEN Status = 'In Progress' THEN 1
            WHEN Status = 'Backlog' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END
```

But I would like to keep only the most important one, so it should take `7 | Done` and then disregard the other two statuses. However, for 5 it needs to take `In Progress`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is typicaly NOT a problem to solve in SQL, but with a data step.

Comment: That's why it was so difficult to figure out, but Gordon showed it was possible so I'm happy I learned something new ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of the `case` expression is a good one.  You want to combine it with aggregation.

For this problem:

```
SELECT id,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Done'
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN 'In Progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'In Progress'
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Backlog' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Backlog'
             ELSE 'Unknown'
        END) as status
FROM t
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would clearly rank the statuses and select the highest one.

Query

```
proc sql; 
  create table want as
  select distinct id, status,
    case 
      when status = 'Done' then 3
      when status = 'In Progress' then 2
      when status = 'Backlog' then 1
      else 0
    end as rank
  from 
  have
  group by id
  having rank = max(rank);
```

If you don't want the computed rank value use `want(drop=rank)` or nest the query and select only `id` and `status` from that.

Data

```
data have;
infile cards dlm='|';
input id status $20.; datalines;
1  | In Progress
2  | In Progress
3  | Done
3  | In Progress
4  | Backlog
5  | Backlog
5  | In Progress
6  | Done
7  | Backlog
7  | In Progress
7  | Done
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a solution that does not use PROC SQL

```
 data have;
    input ID &status & $15.;
    cards;
    1   In Progress
    2   In Progress
    3   Done
    3   In Progress
    4   Backlog
    5   Backlog
    5   In Progress
    6   Done
    7   Backlog
    7   In Progress
    7   Done
    ;
    run;
```

/*Adding a level of importance to each status */

```
data have;
set have;
if status ="Backlog" then importance=1;
if status ="In Progress" then importance=2;
if status ="Done" then importance=3;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by ID importance;
run;

data want;
set have;
by ID;
if last.ID;
drop importance;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but I think I will stick with Gordon's answer as I am using proc sql. But I will keep this in mind for when I will use SAS syntax ;)